# Report in the first plan with SUM Field in footer

Tags: ms-access

I'm stuck in a Report(Modal window "yes" popup "yes" with 2 Groups) opened by a button in a F_Menu form(Modal window "yes" popup "yes" ).
I am looping in a field(T_OV )in the footer which Results from the sum of the field(Net_Payer) in detail
I motion that everything is fine and the calculation is done if the State opens (Modal window "No" popup "No") and the form F_Menu(Modal window "No" popup "No") with these two codes :

```
Private Sub ZonePiedPage_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
[T_OV].Value = TotalPage
'Initialisation de la variable pour la page suivante
TotalPage = 0
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Détail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
TotalPage = Nz(TotalPage + [Net_Payer], 0)
End Sub
```

But in my case, the field (T_OV ) does not display anything
All my work remains dependent on this problem
I ask How to join the file, please?
Thank you very much for all answers
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap2VD1yrtJnXhVL5j9wJM6K4ZvF5?e=bT0WV4

Answer (score 0):

Following is example from my report that provides a page record count and page total of a field. Note the difference from your code in use of Nz() function.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public intPageCount As Integer
Public intPageTotal As Integer

Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
   ' increment variables for each record printed
    intPageCount = intPageCount + 1
    intPageTotal = intPageTotal + Nz(Me.Qty, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub PageFooterSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    'set textboxes in the footer
    tbxPageCount = intPageCount
    tbxPageTotal = intPageTotal
    'reset globals
    intPageCount = 0
    intPageTotal = 0
End Sub
```